# How to Handle Multi Currencies (Precision and Scale) from one Column in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a three columns in table

```
TransactionDate---DateTime
TotalAmount---DECIMAL(18,4)
CurrencyCode---nVarchar(10)

TotalAmount-------------CurrencyCode
1000.5000----------------KD (Kuwaiti Dinnar) which must be 1000.500
5500.2000----------------ETB (Eithopian Birr)
2500.1500----------------USD (United States Dollars) which must be 2500.15
```

I am storing these multi currencies in one column......now i want to get report for each day or month by using SUM() Function in SQL Query.............but SUM must be done based on each currency's precision or scale.
i.e.....If currency is USD   then

```
SUM(2500.15)
```

If currency is KD then

```
SUM(1000.500)
```

and If ETB then

```
SUM(5500.2000)
```

some thing like this..

Comment: Not really clear what "SUM must be done based on each currency's percision or scale" means, could you expand your examples?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just store each currency in its smallest possible unit, as an integer.

For example, if you're storing USD, you should store the value as a "number of pennies" instead of a decimal number of dollars with precision 2.  $1.00 becomes 100.

When you do your "SUM," you'll probably need to "group by currency" for the results to make any sense.  Your client software will need to know how to properly display each currency, but don't let that interfere with how the data is stored in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved by using one column, you should used three columns 
for each currency sum and set their precision accordingly e.g.

```
    Select SUM(2500.15) as USD, SUM(1000.500) as KD, SUM(5500.2000) as ETB
```

Answer (score 0):

Based off your question (vague) you are trying to convert currencies to your type of currency?

i think this is what you might be what your example data looks like:

```
TransactionDate TotalAmount CurrencyCode
2012-06-01      12          KD
2012-06-01      25          KD
2012-06-01      55          ETB
2012-06-01       6          ETB
2012-06-01      13          USD
2012-06-01      10          USD
```

And what logic you are trying to accomplish is ex. If CurrencyCode = KD then sum(TotalAmount)*conversion rate (assuming that is what the numbers that you listed were)

Query:

```
Select
  sum(
    case when [CurrencyCode] = 'KD' then [TotalAmount]*1000.500 
        when [CurrencyCode] = 'ETB' then [TotalAmount]*5500.2000 
        when [CurrencyCode] = 'USD' then [TotalAmount]*2500.1500 
        else 0 end) as [TotalCalcAmount]
From [SomeTable]
--Where [TransactionDate] between '2012-06-01' and '2012-06-30' --Commented out for test purposes
```

SQLFiddle to go with explanation: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ade6e/3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CurrencyCode, SUM(TotalAmount)
FROM dbo.your_table
GROUP BY CurrencyCode
```